# While loop gets terminated before condition is met when backtracking

Tags: java, n-queens

I'm trying to write an iterative program that will help me palce 4 queens on a 4x4 board without them hitting each other. The problem is after looping through each position and backtracking a couple of times my main while loop that keeps looping until a solution is found gets terminated and the program ends even though the condition is not yet met.

I tried the following code:

```
static int[] solve(char[][] board){
    int[] position = new int[4];
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    while(row < 4){
        for(boolean check; column < board.length; column++){
            System.out.println("["+row+","+column+"]");
            check = true;
            for(int queen= 0; queen < row; queen++){
                if (position[queen] == column || queen- position[queen] == row - column || queen + position[queen] == row + column) {
                    check = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(check){
                position[row] = column;
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }
            if(column > 2){
                column = position[--row];
            }
        }
    }
    return position;
}
```

I'm currently getting the following output:

| Q | X | X | X |

| X | X | X | Q |

| X | Q | X | X |

| Q | X | X | X |

To check when exactly the while loop is getting terminated I printed the location (row and column)
`System.out.println("["+row+","+column+"]");` and got the following:

[0,0][1,0][1,1][1,2][2,0][2,1][2,2][2,3][1,3][2,0][2,1][3,0][3,1][3,2][3,3][2,2][2,3]

After backtracking to [2,3] the while loop ends even though my row count is still less than 4.

I was expecting the following output:

| X | Q | X | X |

| X | X | X | Q |

| Q | X | X | X |

| X | X | Q | X |

I tried the code in a different compiler and still got the same wrong output. Is there a logical mistake that I missed out?

I'm new to programming so I'm still trying to get the hang of the fundamentals.

Comment: This is _very_ unusual: `for(boolean check; ...; ...)`. Usually your for-loop would be defined `for(int column = 0; column < board.length; column++ )`

Comment: I tried it and the loop went on forever. It became infinite :/

Comment: *"While loop gets terminated before condition is met"* - no, it doesn't, because you don't have any `break` or `return` or `throw` that would get out of that loop. The only way it happens is when the condition becomes false. So you should investigate why the condition is becoming false when you don't expect it to.

Comment: I think I fixed the while problem for now but now I have a different issue. Will try to figure it out.